# Who can edit the "ask / don't ask" part of the tour?

Tags: support, edits, tour

Who is able to edit this section of the tour of an SE site?

[image: tour]

I know that moderators can edit the [/help/on-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, which is somewhat similar to the above section: both have lists of allowed and disallowed topics. But they are not identical, which means one can be edited independently from the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those sections can be edited by a local site moderator (elected or appointed) or an employee with a diamond. In other words, diamonds can do it :)

Image when you are a moderator ([provided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250730/who-can-edit-the-ask-dont-ask-part-of-the-tour/250733#comment818385_250733) by [Mad Scientist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/151385/mad-scientist)):

> [image]

Comment: @Woodface [proof that mods can edit it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jdtWa.png)

Comment: We can also edit the example question and several other text sections of the tour.