# What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, moderators, help-center, moderator-abilities

I have found out that site moderators can edit certain parts of pages in the Help Center.  In particular, "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" or parts of it can be customized.

What pages or parts of pages are editable exactly?

- Is "[How do I ask a good question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" editable?  This [came up on Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7028/4918) because I'd like to have information about a particular very common category of questions to be included there.
- What other pages in the help center are editable?
- Can moderators change which links show up on [the Help Center main page](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help) and in what order?
- What parts of [the Tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) can be edited?
- Can some the suggestions that show up on the "Ask Question" page under the headings "How to Ask", "How to Format", and "How to Tag" be edited?

This would be useful to know, because when [we discuss site policies of the meta of a StackExchange site](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/246/197), I'd like to propose edits that the moderators can actually carry out.

Comment: Related: [Who can edit the "ask / don't ask" part of the tour?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250730/who-can-edit-the-ask-dont-ask-part-of-the-tour), [Allow mods to edit a section of the about page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136086/allow-mods-to-edit-a-section-of-the-about-page)

Answer (score 27):

Parts of **the Help Center** that moderators can edit:

- An introduction section on the front page (`http://foo.stackexchange.com/help`):

  > [image]
- "What topics can I ask about here?" (`http://foo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic`):

  > [image]

---

Parts of **the Tour** that moderators can edit:

- The introduction paragraph:

  > [image]
- The example question:

  > [image]
- These bullet points:

  > [image]

---

Note that Stack Exchange developers / Community Managers / employees can also edit probably any other section of the site, if you make a good enough case on your per-site meta. For example, the ["Ask Question" page on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) looks like this:

> [image]