# Why is "what can I ask about here" not the first entry in the help center?

Tags: feature-request, support, help-center

On a lot of sites, the first section of the Help Center looks like this:

[image: screen shot from Community Building]

When I go to a site's help center it's almost always to find out what's on-topic there, because I'm considering asking or migrating a question.  Leading with what *not* to ask seems odd to me, and I suspect that to someone not already familiar with SE it could be a little off-putting.

It's not always like this, though; here on MSE we get this, which I've seen on some other sites too:

[image: screen shot from MSE]

That ordering makes a lot more sense to me.  It's also consistent with the tour.  (Maybe "how do I ask a good question?" should also be "above the fold", in the top five somewhere.)

Why the difference?

Can we either make the order consistent across the network and more logical, or give users or moderators the ability to change the order on their sites?

Comment: I often end-up on the wrong topic if I navigate to on topic  via that page because my muscle memory want me to click the 3rd item...anyway: are they maybe ordered in the sequence they are pinned?

Comment: Huh? Didn't even know that varies by site. I thought the on-topic page was the top item in every help center. Weird.

Comment: I agree with you.  Last January [I raised a similar request on the Gardening and Landscaping meta](http://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638). My top priority is moving "How do I ask a good question?" into the top section, since it's where I most frequently send new users. (It's 3rd from the bottom.) Would you allow me to piggyback that onto your request?  According to [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259914), certain Help Center pages may be customizable if a case is made to SE devs/Community Managers/employees on a per-site meta. Does that help you at all?

Comment: @Sue thanks for the suggestion.  See my edit; I've tried to fold your concern in.

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding my concern and adding it in with yours. I couldn't ask for more! Your kindness is appreciated! :)

Comment: @Sue you were right to point out that there's a broader issue, so thanks for that.

Comment: I'm just wondering where this request stands. Does anyone in the management community have a minute to let me know if it's under consideration? Thanks!

Comment: @Sue sorry we missed this before, but I've now finally answered

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer is "ask a CM."

Longer answer is that display order for help center pages is kind of a side effect. There is no tool specifically for choosing the order of these, it depends on what was pinned most recently, and also edited most recently, which is sometimes mod-editable depending on the page, but probably not for all pages....

Without checking any code, I would guess that when the new site setup process runs, the pages are all generated in the same order (the "good" order) by default, but then sometimes when we go customizing in there we unintentionally knock things out of alignment. If you see this, just ping one of us.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you fix the order on [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to put "what can I ask?" first?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Done!

Comment: Pops, this is exciting! Thanks for the assistance and for letting me know. May I consider this my official request to put [How do I ask a good question?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as the third pinned question, or at least in the top few, on [Gardening and Landscaping](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/)? It would make a big difference on our site! Thanks!

Comment: @MonicaCellio Congratulations! Worldbuilding looks great, I'm really happy for you!

Comment: Just testing to see if I get a Ericson's revenge hat...