# Still HTTP links in /tour on various sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, tour

> **<Something> Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for <some people>. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about <scope>.

The text above is the first paragraph in the `/tour` page on almost every site. The above link is in HTTP not HTTPS. See for SU:

[image]

I only tested a few sites, and MSE is one of a few sites whose `/tour` have all links in HTTPS. I'll update this list when I'm happy to do so.

- The tour page is **OK** on MSE, ell.SE/ell.MSE (they contain HTTPS links)
- The tour page on SO/MSO, SU/MSU, SF/MSF, android.SE/android.MSE, **security.SE/security.MSE** (ironic) contains HTTP links

More interestingly, the tour page on SA (Stack Apps) contains an amalgam of HTTP and HTTPS! That's confusing. See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: The tour of [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/tour) has been fixed in the mean time, I assume by a dev as mods can't edit that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed the links on all of the `/tour` pages uncovered by Glorfindel's query

> Why h-t-t-p?
> Aren't all tour links secure?
> Now all s-s-l

Answer (score 9):

♦ moderators can [edit that blurb of text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/295232); if they haven't done that, a boilerplate one (based on the site name and topic) is shown, unless the site is [old enough to not have this feature](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/7279/revisions). The link in the boilerplate one has been migrated to HTTPS; otherwise, the local moderators could do so manually.

Since these blurbs are stored as posts in the database (just like questions and answers), we can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to get a [list of affected sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/1433271/tours-with-http-links). I've already gone ahead and updated the link for Ask Different. If you're a moderator on one of the 66 other sites and you read this, you know what to do :)

Comment: Great work! I wonder why the Community♦ bot doesn't step in and fix those as it does (did?) with regular posts though.

Comment: @41686d6564 the bot only repaired questions and answers. Other post types, like tag wikis and excerpts, were not. (I don't know why, staff has to answer that.)